# drawling perpendicular line to two set of points in pixel coordinates?

Tags: geometry, jogl

For example, I have points {x1 = 70,y1 = 200},{x2 = 50,y2 = 400} in pixel coordinates. If I am to draw  a perpendicular to this line, with the start point as (x1,y1) how would I go about getting the end point of the perpendicular line in jogl?

Here's what I have tried so far:
Calculated the normal : 
dx = x2-x1; dy = y2-y1;

drawLine{(x1,y1},(dy,dx)}

I have tried negative values for dx and dy. couldn't get the perpendicular line.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (x1 + dy, y1 - dx) for a clockwise-rotated line, and (x1 - dy, y1 + dx) for anti-". The main thing was you forgot to add the world coordinates onto the displacement vector for the second point. (and also some sign-related stuff)